# Problems with removing an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I got a function that removes an element 1 second after you double click it, using the target Event and removeChild. As shown below:

```
function remove(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    setTimeout(function(){
        target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
    }, 1000);
}
document.addEventListener("dblclick", remove, false);
```

It does work, you doubleclick the element (only one square in this case) and it disappears one second later. However, if you double click the space outside it (the body i suppose) then everything gets removed. jsfiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/8ma5ayqj/

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, without referring to the shape directly? Like if there were a couple of different divs i wanted this to happen to.

Comment: Your Event is attached to `document`. Attach it to the Element itself and you won't even have to use the Event Object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if there are multiple divs on the page that i want this to apply on? Say 20 different square divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve set `addEventListener` to the entire `document`. You could write something like this:

```
yourSquareNode.addEventListener("dblclick", remove, false);
```

Or you could check in the function, whether the target is the blue square itself.

```
if(e.target == yourSquareNode){
  …
}
```

Otherwise the event applies to the `document`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if there are multiple divs on the page that i want this to apply on? Say 20 different square divs.

Comment: Then use the `if` statement from the second code block and test for certain properties. E. g. all the `div`s that are to disappear have the `willDisappear` class. Then you apply the event listener to the `document` and test something like `if(e.target.classList.contains('willDisappear'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Learn this:

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
E('#clickId').onclick = function(){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
}
//]]>
```